# Center a tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

Cantering means shifting a vector so that its mean will be zero.

I want to center each row of a tensor, for example:

```
A = |1 , 1|    A_center = |0, 0|
    |0 , 4|               |-2,2|
```

For this, I use this approach:

```
a_center  = a - a.mean(dim=1).unsqueeze(1)
```

I want to know if there is any built-in way to center a tensor in PyTorch. Because I know there are built-in functions for length normalization, I assume there might be a function for tensor centering too, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I dont think there is a specific function in Pytorch for that

Comment: The closest is the torch.sub() function to subtract two tensors element-wise that could be better performant in that operation `a_center = torch.sub(a, a.mean(dim=1).unsqueeze(1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now there is no built-in function in Pytorch. Use this:

```
x_centered = x - x.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True)
```